# Particle System is floating in the air and not on the surface

Tags: modifiers, particles

I need help, how can I make the grass stick to the surface? There's a lot of options here that if I change it, it moves the grass closer to the floor but smaller the more I reduce it.

[image: Even if I change the Orientation Axis to Velocity/Hair, all of the grass will lie down.]

Comment: Is the particle system on the ground ?

Comment: Select the grass ( the object you used as an instance object, not the particles themselves) in edit mode and move it around on each of the different axes (X,Y,Z) until you find the one that makes the grass particles move up and down. Move your grass object until the grass particles are flush with the surface of the emitter object (the ground plane)

Comment: The grass (The object that I placed in render particle system) yes is on the ground and moving them in edit mode moves the particle, but is it possible to like automatically move them on the surface? because some are halfway inside the ground (the ground is not flat)

Comment: Share your simplified file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ it's hard to see what's going on, it seems to me like you emit particles from flat plane and you want to let them follow curvature of green ground object?

Comment: Make sure the origin point of your grass object is actually located on the mesh

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=g456s1Qy" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/g456s1Qy/)

Here's the file

Answer (score 2):

The reason why your grass is not where it should be is that the object's origin is way off from the mesh, -30.5 m in X direction, 3.1 m in Y direction and 0.4 m in Z direction. That's the reason why they are not close to the surface or sometimes sinking in, because they are "growing" more than 30 m away from where they are "born".

[image: origin off]

To get them distributed correctly you should set the origin close to the bottom of the grass mesh (image below). One way to do it: go to *Edit Mode*, select the bottom vertices of the grass, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > *Cursor to Selected*. Then back into *Object Mode*, right-click on the grass object, *Set Origin* > *Origin to 3D Cursor*.

[image: new grass origin]

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I found out the answer. Yes you can move your particles by moving the main object (the instance object) in edit mode, but if you want them to follow the curvature  of your land and avoid some particles from going halfway inside your land, you can use weight paint.

Comment: Sorry, this is not correct. This might be a workaround that solved your problem in this case, but you don't need weight painting to place hair particles on a plane. I'll write an answer.